# upload files in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a website in MVC4 C#, which allow you to upload files to a folder inside the project's folder,
For some reason the controller can't find the uploaded file. The "db.music.Add(newsong)" doesn't add the song path and name to the DB. here are the View,Controller and Model of the project.
thanks for your help!

---

Index.cshtml - VIEW

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Your Music</h2>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" >
    <input type="submit" />
```

MusicController.cs - CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

   if (file.ContentLength > 0)
       {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            MVPDB db = new MVPDB();
            UploadMusic newsong = new UploadMusic();
            newsong.userId = 11;
            newsong.songName = file.FileName.ToString();
            newsong.songPath = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName).ToString();

            db.music.Add(newsong);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UserFiles/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

---

Music.cs - MODEL

```
namespace MVP.Models
{
public class Music
    {
        [Key]
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public string songName { get; set; }
        public string songPath { get; set; }

    }
public class UploadMusic
    {
        [Required]
        public int userId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string songName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string songPath { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: What does "can't find the uploaded file" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form doesn't contains action. Try this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Music", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, but I don't know where to put this code (I'm new on MVC4) can you please give me another hand?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38970/Implementing-HTTP-File-Upload-with-ASP-NET-MVC    this post may help. Just change it to Razor view.